# Speech recognition volume of voice

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I have a very sensitive microphone and even when I whisper I can hear clearly what I am saying but when I use this library I almost have to scream. Any ideas. Without `adjust_for_ambient_noise`, the code is in an endless loop.

```
import speech_recognition as sr

listener=sr.Recognizer()

try:
    with sr.Microphone(device_index=1) as source:
        print("start")
        listener.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        voice=listener.listen(source,timeout=5)
        print("stop")
        command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
        print(command)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do here is make sure that the Microphone source is the *expected* source. Is any other microphone connected? Is there some way with the `speech_recognition` package that you could play back what has been recorded so that you know exactly what the `sr.Microphone()` function is getting as input?